# How to set z-index on tinyMCE toolbar?

Tags: jquery, css, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE editor plugin. It converts texareas into iframes and a toolbar appears at top of the text content. It is working perfectly.

Sometimes there are some videos above the content. So when I click textarea, the toolbar appears but video player above the content hides it behind itself.

**Is there any way to change the z-index of the toolbar ? (Preferable)
Or should I change the location of toolbar ???**

Here is my code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        editor_selector : "combo123",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "save, paste, autoresize, asciimath, asciisvg",
        theme_advanced_styles: "Foo=foo, Bar=bar",
        content_css : "/css/tiny_mce.css"
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also set the z-index right after initialization using the setup param

```
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed){
        $('tr.mceFirst').css('z-index','1');
    });
}),
```

Comment: Yes. It is working for me using `$(".mceExternalToolbar").css( 'z-index', '1000' );`

Answer (score 9):

Increase the **z-index** for tinymce so it does not get overridden from another div

```
<style>
    .tox-tinymce-aux{z-index:99999999999 !important;}
</style>
```

Comment: Explain briefly about your provided answer.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for, modify the z-index from my CSS file

Answer (score 2):

The tinyMCE is transposing over the textarea, so put the textarea into a container and set the z-index on the container.

```
<div style="z-index: 10;"><textarea></textarea></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the video player is Flash based, this won't help.

This page claims adding "opaque" to the "wmdode" param of the player is a solution, but I haven't tested it:
http://slightlymore.co.uk/flash-and-the-z-index-problem-solved/

Comment: Unless you set wmode to transparent.

Answer (score 1):

**to your Notice you have added two content_css, it should be only one content_css**

**actually the content_css should have your site .css adding purpose ,,so for textarea you can restrict in your css and you can set the width and height**

```
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        editor_selector : "combo123",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "save, paste, autoresize, asciimath, asciisvg",

        theme_advanced_styles: "Foo=foo, Bar=bar",

        content_css : "/css/yoursite.css"
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved using this

```
$(document).on('focusin', function (e) {
   if ($(e.target).closest(".mce-window").length) 
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this works in angular, add it to your component.scss

```
::ng-deep .tox-tinymce-inline {
  z-index: 200 !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`tinymce.ui.FloatPanel.zIndex = 99;`